# Make divs move with mouse movement in realtime without delay

Tags: javascript

I have created a simple game for fun, where you try to click a button with your mouse, but everytime you click the button it moves to a random position and some fake cursors appear that move in the same way as the mouse cursor. to make that possible I used the following method

- I tracked my mouse movement and store my previous mouse position.
- I calculate how much the mouse has moved in x and y direction and apply the same to the images (fake mouse cursors).

[VISIT THIS LINK TO SEE THE PROBLEM IN LIVE](https://kiransbaliga.github.io/Where-is-my-mouse/)

The problem is that the fake images moves slower and can be easily distinguished by movement.

```js
const images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
let lastMouseX = null;
let lastMouseY = null;

// Start fresh if mouse leaves screen
document.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
  lastMouseX = null;
  lastMouseY = null;
});

document.addEventListener('mousemove', (ev) => {
  // Do nothing if this is the first event
  if (lastMouseX !== null) {
    const deltaX = ev.x - lastMouseX;
    const deltaY = ev.y - lastMouseY;
    for (const img of images) {
      let newLeft = img.offsetLeft + deltaX;
      let newTop = img.offsetTop + deltaY;
      img.style.left = newLeft + 'px';
      img.style.top = newTop + 'px';
    }
  }
  lastMouseX = ev.x;
  lastMouseY = ev.y;
});
```

Comment: Don't post third-party website links for problems with plain HTML/CSS/JS code, [edit] your post and [put your code in](/help/how-to-ask) as a runnable snippet using the `<>` button. On a "why it doesn't look the same" note: the mouse cursor is owned by the Operating System, and updates its position _way_ faster than your screen can refresh. However, the browser can only render things at the frame rate of your screen, so your mouse cursor is _always_ going to feel or even move smoother than a frame based animation can mimic (unless you have a particularly bad mouse).

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you cannot achieve *perfect* follow when using pointermove/mousemove Events. An element position will always slightly lag behind the actual pointer, specially noticeable on fast mouse move.

**Solution**

What I would do instead is hide your "real" mouse pointer using `cursor: none;` and place a pointer image right underneath the *hidden* mouse pointer as well.

- all your "fake" pointers will be the same (even regardless of the browser)
- your "fake" pointers will all move the same way.

Another suggestion to **improve performance** is:

- don't move every single "fake pointer". Instead, move only a single parent element `#pointers` where the pointer images are (randomly) absolute positioned within that parent element.
- the main pointer will actually be that parent `#pointers` centered background image

Final example:

```js
// Utility functions:

const el = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelector(sel);
const elNew = (tag, prop) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), prop);
const repeat = (n, cb) => [...Array(n)].forEach((_, i) => cb(i));
const rand = (min, max) => Math.random() * (max - min) + min;


// Game:

const elBody = el("body");
const elPointers = el("#pointers");
const elBtn = el("#btn");
let totPointers = 0;

const createPointers = () => {
  totPointers += ~~rand(3, 10); // between 3 and 10 new pointers
  elPointers.innerHTML = ""; // Remove old pointers
  repeat(totPointers, (i) => {
    const elPointer = elNew("div", {className: "pointer"});
    elPointer.style.left = `${rand(0, 100)}%`;
    elPointer.style.top  = `${rand(0, 100)}%`;
    elPointers.append(elPointer);
  });
};

const moveBtn = () => {
  elBtn.style.left = `${rand(5, 95)}%`;
  elBtn.style.top  = `${rand(5, 95)}%`;
};

const changeBackground = () => {
  const hue = ~~rand(0, 360);
  elBody.style.background = `hsl(${hue}, 80%, 50%)`;
};

const levelUp = () => {
  createPointers();
  moveBtn();
  changeBackground();
};

const movePointers = (evt) => {
  const xCenter = evt.clientX / elBody.offsetWidth - 0.5;
  const yCenter = evt.clientY / elBody.offsetHeight - 0.5;
  elPointers.style.translate = `${xCenter * 100}% ${yCenter * 100}%`;
};

// Events
elBtn.addEventListener("click", levelUp);
elBody.addEventListener("pointermove", movePointers);

// Init
moveBtn();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: none;  /* HIDE THE CURSOR! */  
}

body {
  height: 100dvh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#pointers {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  /* This is the actual main fake cursor! */
  background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zt6te.png") calc(50% + 2px) calc(50% + 14px) no-repeat;
  pointer-events: none; /* allow click-through */
}

#btn {
  position: absolute;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0.5rem 0.7rem;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  transition: background 0.3s;
  translate: -50% -50%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.pointer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 25px;
  height: 32px;
  background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zt6te.png");
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">I am here</button>
<div id="pointers"></div>
```

Comment: thanks so much. It didn't occur to me to use a fake mouse. I tried it out and works pretty well. Thanks again